# Dataset Format for fine tuning deepset/roberta-base-squad2 hugging face transformer model

Tags: nlp, tensorflow, pytorch, transformer, huggingface

I have been trying to fine tune the roberta model for QnA to my specific domain (healthcare).
I am unable to find the correct way to provide the dataset format to the tokenizer in order to fine tune the model.

Sample Dataset format ->

```
train_data = (
{
    'context':'context for the training data',
    'answers':{'text':['answer 1'],'answer_start':[115],'answer_end':[138] },
    'question':'question1'
},
{
    'context':'context for the training data',
    'answers':{'text':['answer 2'],'answer_start':[115],'answer_end':[138] },
    'question':'question2'
},
{
    'context':'context for the training data',
    'answers':{'text':['answer 3'],'answer_start':[115],'answer_end':[138] },
    'question':'question3'
}
)
```

Can anyone help me with the correct format to provide to tokenizer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate what error message/results you got from using the stated data set and why you think it's wrong (in case it wasn't an error message)